# How to add a menubar to a QFrame with QtDesigner?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer, qmenubar

I have created a `QFrame` with Qt designer, and now I'm trying to add a menubar. So far I have seen that I maybe should have used `QMainWindow` but I can't change the type anymore and I don't see any option to attach a menu.

I have tried to create an empty `QMainWindow` to see how it is done there. But I can only see a menubar entry with now way how to add menus and items to it. Using google also didn't yield anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any way to add a `QMenuBar` if you don't choose to create an empty `QMainWindow`, but if you do that, typing text into the "type here" area and pressing enter creates a new `QMenu` in the menu bar. There is also "type here" areas for each created menu, allowing you to add items (ie `QAction`s) to menus. It worked at least with QtCreator 5.3.1.

Comment: I have to try that. So I should create that mainwindow, and then attach the frame, I already have, as a subwindow?

Comment: Yes, I think this works, whilst keeping all the changes you made to your frame.

Comment: Thx! Do you know why I have a `centralwidget` which doesn't seem to expand to the full mainwindow size?

Comment: It can be because the `centralwidget` you created have no layout. With a horizontal or vertical layout, your widget will normally fit the size of its parent, ie your mainwindow.

Comment: I managed it now, though it is still not 100% clear to me. :)